# How to add swap file to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, swap

I have at Ubuntu 12.04 swap size the same as my RAM - 1Gb.

I want to increase this a little bit, till 3Gb. Increase 2Gb of swap size.

I read [SwapFaq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) but I can't understand how to keep having this swap capacity that I have and add additional space?

Here you can see my disk structure with gparter:

[image: disk usage by gparter]

I hope someone can help me increase swap size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to resize the sda1 partition, and in order to do that you must unmount the partition. But you will not be able to do that if you log in. Backup your data. Then restart and boot from a live CD/usb. Don't install but use the live option. Open Gparted and resize the sda1 partition in order to free the amount you wish. Then resize swap. Close the session, remove the live distribution and log in.

This tutorial might help understand better the process.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8j3APIdOJu0

But first, back up your data.

Comment: That's resizing swap partition not adding a swap file. Different things.

Comment: @Elfy What do you thing about adding swap file? It's better than change swap size?

Comment: Up to you to be honest. Depends on what you want to do afterwards. If you're going to be enabling and using hibernate then you'll want to resize swap partition or create a new one. You can't (as far as I am aware) use swap file for that. If you prefer graphical ways of doing things then using gparted is easy - though can be time consuming while it's resizing your / partition.